# MySQLi executing multiple unrelated queries and also executing a prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am creating a dynamic PHP website where just about everything on the site, including navigation is generated dynamically. I am creating a test page (test.php), as I am new to PHP, and am having some issues when doing multiple queries plus a prepared statement as I have a search form on the page. Basically want I am doing, is in the SQL, creating a query for top level navigation items where parent = 0, and also a prepared statement searching for items in another table based on the search. The two queries are unrelated. In my body, where I have the navigation displaying, I want to nest another query to then search for navigation items with a parent that equals the current ID of the top level menu item. This is the SQL at the top of my document:

```
try {
    //db connection is here

    $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM menu_items WHERE item_parent = 0';
    $result1 = $db->query($sql1);

    if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
        $sqlSearch = "SELECT id, css_body, page_title, meta_description, meta_keywords, heading, details, layout
            FROM content
            WHERE ( details LIKE ? OR heading LIKE ? )";
        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
        if (!$stmt->prepare($sqlSearch)) {
            $error = $stmt->error;
        } else {
        $var1 = '%' . $_GET['searchterm'] . '%';
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $var1, $var1);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $css_body, $page_title, $meta_description, $meta_keywords, $heading, $details, $layout);
    }

    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

In my body:

```
    <ul>
    <?php while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $row["item_title"]; ?>

    <?php $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM menu_items WHERE item_parent = ' . $row["item_id"];
        $result2 = $db->query($sql2);
        if (isset($result2)) { ?>

        <ul>
         <?php while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $row2["item_title"]; ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
   </ul>    
        <?php } ?>
   </li>
   <?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

With that code, if I just go straight to the test.php page, without doing a search, everything displays fine. For example, the page would look like:

```
<ul>
<li>Page 1</li>
<ul>
<li>Sub Page 1</li>
<li>Sub Page 2</li>
</ul>
<li>Page 2</li>
</ul>
```

However if I then submit the search form on the page (which submits to the same page, url would look like test.php?searchterm=my+search&search=Go), then I get an error. The page will display the first LI, but then when it hits that second query it just completely stops. So it looks like:

```
<ul>
<li>Page 1</li>
```

If I removed everything for the prepared statement, the "sub-navigation"/nested query works fine. If I removed the SQL/php for the menu_items, the prepared statement works fine. The issue is when I put everything together on one page. If anyone could explain what I may be doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm new to prepared statements and object oriented PHP. I learned all of the above after watching Accessing Databases with Object-Oriented PHP with David Powers on Lynda.com.

Here is the entire page code:

```
<?php
try {
    require_once '_includes/mysqli-connect.php';
    $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM menu_items WHERE item_parent = 0';
    $result1 = $db->query($sql1);

    if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
        $sqlSearch = "SELECT heading, details FROM content WHERE ( details LIKE ? OR heading LIKE ? )";
        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
        if (!$stmt->prepare($sqlSearch)) {
            $error = $stmt->error;
        } else {
            $var1 = '%' . $_GET['searchterm'] . '%';
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $var1, $var1);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($heading, $details);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php if (isset($error)) {
    echo "<p>$error</p>";
}
?>
<ul>
  <?php while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
  <li><?php echo $row["item_title"]; ?>
    <?php 
    $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM menu_items WHERE item_parent = ' .$row["item_id"];
    $result2 = $db->query($sql2);
    if (isset($error)) {
        echo "<p>$error</p>";   
    }
    if (isset($result2)) { ?>
    <ul>
      <?php while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
      <li><?php echo $row2["item_title"]; ?></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php }
    ?>
  </li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>

<!-- Search form and results below -->
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <p>
    <label for="searchterm">Enter a name or part of one:</label>
    <input type="search" name="searchterm" id="searchterm"> <input type="submit" name="search" value="Go"></p>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($error)) {
    echo "<p>$error</p>";   
}
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
if ($numrows) {
    echo "<p>Total results found: ". $numrows;  
} else {
    echo "No Results";  
}

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<p>Heading: " . $heading . "</p>";    
    echo $details;
    echo "<hr/>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
$result1->free();
$stmt->free_result();
if (isset($db)) {
    $db->close();
} ?>
```

Comment: you have an error before you end you li  you have ? when you need ?> Also, try moving your var1 declaration above your bind->param statement.

Comment: I must have accidently deleted the > when editing the code on here, but it is in my actual file code, so that isn't the issue. I moved the var1 declaration as you suggested but issue remains.

Comment: I'm not seeing your `if (isset($_GET['search'])) {` being closed anywhere. You should really consider breaking your code out into functions. It is quite hard to read the way it is now. Also, it doesn't look like you're actually doing any filtering based on the search input.

Comment: Patrick - I edited the code to show everything in the beginning, which shows the if isset closing. Since I am new to this style of PHP, I haven't really learned functions yet. I would like to get this approach working correctly first before I move forward with functions.

Comment: You should check your error log.  I would imagine that your sub-menu query is probably throwing an error related to the fact that you're attempting to execute a new query before you fetch the results of your search query (you don't have a fetch for that query at all).

Comment: I checked the error log, and it is giving me the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object on line 46.

Line 46 is this one:  <?php while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

Which would indicate there is an error in the query, but I don't understand what it would be.

Comment: Patrick - Updated my post with code for entire page which shows the fetch for the search query.

Comment: I know you're new to PHP, but just like any other language you should learn to build classes and function, this way you build your site in modular pieces, especially if they are not related, if they are then you should somehow join the query

Comment: Time for some basic debugging. After `$result2 = $db->query($sql2);` add `if(!$result2){echo $db->error; exit;}`. That should give you a better indication of what the real problem is.

Comment: I added the debug code. The message it gives me is: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the issue. Basically, the problem is that MySQLi thinks there might be more results and it won't run any further statements or queries until the results from the search query are stored or the statement is closed. I didn't do either origionally until after I tried running the sub-nav query. I now moved this line of code $stmt->store_result();  under $stmt_bind_result($heading, $details); and now all the queries work.

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($heading, $details);
$stmt->store_result();
```